# Is C++'s std::thread a wrapper for pthread on all platforms?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm learning the use of std::thread, I used to think std::thread is a completely different threading library independent of pthread , I use the following code to test:

```cpp
void run(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" <<endl;
}

int main(void) {
    std::thread t(run);
    t.join();
}
```

I thought it could be compiled directly via:

```cpp
$ g++ main.cpp -o main
```

But it tells me that the "pthread_create" function is not defined:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZpJ3EI.o: in function `std::thread::thread<void (&)(), , void>(void (&)())':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFvvEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x2f): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error：ld return 1
```

I have to add the link for pthread:

```cpp
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -lpthread
```

My OS is archlinux/manjaro, the C++ standard version is C++ 17.

Do I also need to link pthreads if I'm on another OS?

Comment: No.  `std::thread` is not required to be a thread wrapper for pthread.   However, some implementations do implement `std::thread` and other related classes/functionality using pthreads.   It's an implementation choice.   In those cases which do use pthreads, quality of implementation concerns will determine whether it is necessary to explicitly link in the pthreads library or not.

Comment: obviously `std::thread` can't use `pthread` on platforms where `pthread` isn't available. \*nix aren't the only platforms out there

Comment: `std::thread` wraps whatever the underlying platform supplies to implement threads. If that's `pthread`, so be it. If it's sitting over Windows threads, or vrtx threads, or whatever the cool kids are using these days...

Comment: I remember that pthread belongs to the threading model of posix, but the windows system mainly only uses the win32 thread library. If the compiler is not g++, but vc++, do you need to link pthread?

Comment: @aszswaz Unlikely, but again, it is really up to the `std::thread` implementation to decide that. There are pthread implementations available for Windows.